# Ubuntu 11.10 under VMware full-screen resolution problem

Tags: resolution, vmware

I am running ubuntu 11.10 under VMware 9.0 (Host on Win 8). I have installed VMware tools. When I log into ubuntu, sometimes screen resolution changes to appropriate settings without problem and sometimes it does not.

When it doesn't fit itself, the appropriate screen resolution (1600 * 900 16:9) is not in the display resolution lists and so I can not fit the screen manually.

What is the problem?

**UPDATE:** I installed gnome desktop and when I login with Gnome-Desktop option, it is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Test to go to View -> Fit Guest Now in VMware

If this doesn't work try to check the VMware tools settings inside the guest. If that does't work try to reinstall VMware tools as administrator. Another method is to uncheck the autofit guest, and then manually inside the guest choose the right resolution.

Hope that solves your problem. If not, write a comment.

Comment: `View->Fit Guest Now` is disabled.  I want to choose the right resolution, but it's now there! 1600*900 is not in the list.

Comment: Try the other methods I gave you, maybe they will work. ;)